# Yii2 Navbar brandLabel on the right

Tags: yii2

How can I put the only the company label on the right side of the navbar, rather then it's default place in the left?
All the other navbar items I would like to leave on the left.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add these stylings to your CSS:

```
.navbar-header {
    float: right;
}

.navbar-header a {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-right {
    float: left !important;
}
```

Not recommended, but you can put it with style tags into the layouts/main.php file.